# C++ How to use MIT Kerberos with libpq?

Tags: c++, postgresql, kerberos, libpq

I have a windows c++ application which uses libpq to work with PostgreSQL.

My code is:

```
std::string conninfo = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test connect_timeout=10";
_connectionHandlerPtr = PQconnectdb(conninfo.c_str());
```

Now I need to use MIT Kerberos for authentication. 
I installed MIT Kerberos.

What I need to do in my code?
What I need to change in PostgreSQL config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to change anything in your code. A quick look at `psql` suggests that all the Kerberos support is handled via `libpq`, so `psql` doesn't have to care; the same should be true of your app.

If your system is set up for Kerberos auth and has a ticket, you should just need to set `krbsrvname` in your libpq connection string. See [the libpq parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS). On Windows you may also need to set `gsslib` to `gssapi` if you want to use MIT Kerberos instead of SSPI.

Comment: Thnx, yes I want to use MIT Kerberos. Could you say: what is the principal forma t should I use in this case? They write it must be like this servicename\name@realm? Also, what parameters I need to use in conninfo? Username? password?

Comment: Password is meaningless with kerberos. You'll want the username if it doesn't match the user's system local username (of course, it must match the kerberos ticket) and the service name. The rest of the options like any realm override are set by MIT kerberos environment variables or `krb5.conf` if required; see http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/env_variables.html

Comment: Should I create user in PGSQL in format servicename\user1@realm or it will be only user 'user1' in PGSQL? And in conninfo I use  'servicename\user1@realm'? Little bit confused with formats